# Make scrollbar visible and customize it only in a specific div (i.e. in left side menu)

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, visible, section508

I have left side menu that has `overflow-y: scroll` property set and fixed height (smaller than whole page's height). I want scrollbar to be visible always only inside this left menu. Tried with `-webkit-scrollbar` and `-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` but it applies on whole page (but not on left side menu).

Comment: Share your code you have tried. @qwerty

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something like that a while ago. I recommend using SASS/SCSS, its way easier to make CSS selectors.

Anyway, for it to take effect, you must specify the element that will have the custom scrollbar.

**CSS**

```
.div-class::-webkit-scrollbar {
    // custom scrollbar here
}}
```

**SCSS**

```
.div-class {
    &::webkit-scrollbar {
        // custom scrollbar here
    }
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        // etc etc
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp, if you know how to customize the scrollbar, than you only have to get the specified one of the box you want to edit (side-menu in your case) that can be achieved by adding this pseudo element to your side bar selector like this:
`.side-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {}`